# Dependent list box menus, values in Exacttarget Data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, dataextensions, landing-page

I need to create a landing page collect prospect data. In the page I have to create to drop down menus (HTML: Select). The first one is to select car brand and the second one to select the model of the brand.

I have a data extension with all brands and models, the data extension is monthly updated. The challenge I have is that I do not know how to make that the second drop down only displays the models of the brand selected in the first select component.

I think that I cannot use AMPscript, How could I do that? I am not sure if I could access the data extension using JavaScript.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can either load the page up with all possible values in the select and then use client-side JS to filter them down or you can do an AJAX call to another page that serves up only those options for your drop-down.

I'd recommend using [SSJS](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/server_side_javascript/) instead of AMPScript, but you'd still need to use client-side JS to control the behavior after page-load.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I think I can build easily a page that serves only the options for the second drop down but I am not familiar with AJAX calls any sample of AJAX calls wills highly appreciated.

Comment: Here are a couple of jQuery AJAX examples: 
http://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/WQXXT/
http://jsfiddle.net/clickthelink/Uwcuz/1/